# Matlab GUI always on foreground

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-guide

I created two GUI in Matlab: `gui1` and `gui3`.
I don't know why but `gui3` is always in the foreground. 
If, when `gui3` is running, I try to click on Matlab or something else, I hear the classic 'beep' of Windows and `gui3` is always stay in the foreground.
Why?

[Here's a gif](https://www.dropbox.com/s/izg3nqz3t0o3dfe/gifGUI.gif?dl=0) to better understand what's happening.

I searched in the Inspector but didn't find anything to do to my case. How can I fix it?
I don't write here my code because I don't know what to write, but if you need it, I will.

Thank you

Comment: Does one have the `WindowStyle` property set to `modal`? `modal` means it will always be on top. If so, try changing the `WindowStyle` to `normal`

Comment: Thanks I solved!

Comment: Will do, thanks @m7913d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will happen if the GUI has the `WindowStyle` property set to `modal`. `modal` means it will always be on top and will block the rest of the Matlab GUI. Try changing the `WindowStyle` to `normal`.